# Node-forever restartall and child processes

Tags: node.js, debian, forever

We have a main node process that spawns a number of child processes with `child_process.fork()`, which themselves each spawn a helper child process. We are using node-forever to manage the lifetime of the main node processes, and often use `forever restartall` to restart this.

One problem we are seeing occasionally is that the grandchild processes will fail to terminate, and we end up with duplicated child processes running.  Ie. what should be this:

```
Main Process
  Child Process 1
    Grandchild Process 1
  Child Process 2
    Grandchild Process 2
```

Ends up like this after `restartall`:

```
Main Process
  Child Process 1
    Grandchild Process 1
  Child Process 2
    Grandchild Process 2

    Grandchild Process 1
    Grandchild Process 2
```

Unsurprisingly this causes lots of weird problems and we usually have to restart the whole server (or kill processes manually, if we can establish which are the old ones).

As I understand it, forever issues a `SIGTERM` message to the process when it does a restartall.  I believe this message should cascade down to the child and grandchild processes (but please correct me if I've made a false assumption there).  *Since this problem only occurs maybe once in 100, perhaps it's something related to timing?*

**What circumstances could cause the grandchild processes to fail to terminate? How to mitigate this?**

OS is Debian Squeeze.

EDIT: My initial description was a bit over simplified.  I've updated it to include all the details.

EDIT2 : We don't use forever anymore.  I recommend [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)

Comment: Maybe try something advanced like [*PM2*](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2). If your process setup isn't dynamic, you can launch multiple processes "under" pm2 and later just do `pm2 reload all`.

Comment: @S.D. Thanks - I need to keep the Main>Child hierarchy though, as these child processes do specific jobs and communicate back to the main process.

Comment: What OS are you running this on?

Comment: Debian Squeeze (I'll update the question with that).

Comment: I agree with @S.D. node-forever is a lost cause and PM2 is definitely the way to go. It's documented thoroughly, has close integration with OSes (startup services, bash-completion, etc.) and has a modular plugin system.

Comment: @Tony Yeah, we ditched forever last year, and are much happier with pm2.

Comment: @UpTheCreek Maybe you can edit your question and add PM2 as your final solution? I think it would help other people avoiding a lot of confusions, as I came here straight via Google search.

Comment: @Tony - Done. Not sure what kind of confusion this will avoid though (I don't consider using pm2 to be an answer to this question).

Comment: @UpTheCreek Thanks, "confusion" might have been a wrong word but recommending a better software is always good :)

Comment: @UpTheCreek did you find any solution for this?